# Can we prove digit $b_{t} \geq a_{l}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given $a,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a>1$

Let $$a^{x} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{a}i^{n}>a^{x-1}$$

Define : $a^{x}-\sum_{i=1}^{a}i^{n} = k$

Converting $k$ in a base $a$,

$k = (a_{l} ... a_2 a_1)_{a}$ where $a_{l} \ne 0$

Let $a+1=b$

$$b^{y} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{b}i^{n}>b^{y-1}$$

Define : $b^{y}-\sum_{i=1}^{b}i^{n} = k'$

Converting $k'$ in a base $b$,

$k' = (b_{t} ... b_2 b_1)_{b}$ where $b_{t} \ne 0$

> > **Question**
> >
> > *Can we prove $b_{t} \geq a_{l}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?*
> >
> > *If not then can we disprove by counterexample?*

**Example**

Let $n=2$ and $a=3 \implies b=4$

$3^3-(1^2+2^2+3^2)= 13 = (111)_{3}$

So $a_l = 1$

And $4^3-(1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2)= 34 = (202)_{4}$

So $b_{t} = 2$

Here our assumption is true $b_t \geq a_l$

Comment: What is $\Bbb W$?

Comment: @Martin $\mathbb{W} $ denote whole number

Comment: That is usually denoted as $\Bbb Z$ (all integers) or $\Bbb N$ (positive integers).

Comment: Ok now I convert $\mathbb{W}$ to $ \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

So we are considering the summation $\sum_{i=1}^n i^d$ in base $n$. A quick observation yields
$$
n^{d+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n n^d \geq \sum_{i=1}^n i^d \geq n^d.
$$

Therefore, if $k = n^{d+1} - \sum_{i=1}^n i^d$, the most significant digit of $k$ in base $n$ equals
$$
n - \Bigg\lceil\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d}\Bigg\rceil.
$$

To show that the most significant digit is non-decreasing as $n$ increases, it is equivalent to show
$$
\Bigg(n+1 - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^d}{(n+1)^d}\Bigg) - \Bigg(n-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d}\Bigg) \geq 0.
$$

This is true since
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^d}{(n+1)^d} = \frac{(n+1)^d + \sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{(n+1)^d} = 1 + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{(n+1)^d} < 1 + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d}.
$$

Comment: How $
n^{d+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n n^d \geq \sum_{i=1}^n i^d \geq n^d.
$??

Comment: Maybe you will see by writing down actual examples.

Comment: if I put n=2 and d=3 in the formula $
n - \Bigg\lfloor\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d}\Bigg\rfloor.
$ then gives $2$ but in $(111)_{3}$ there is no such digit $2$. What do you mean?

Comment: That should be a ceiling, and is fixed. Also for $n=2$ one will need a different treatise, but should be true, since the most significant digit in base $2$ is always 1.